# Create APA Table from margins()

Tags: r, stargazer

I use the margins library in R to calculate AME's from a linear model. Normally I would use the stargazer library to create table which I can use in an academic paper. This is sadly, only possible for regression objects. Is there a efficant way to produce a similar table for the results returned from margins e.g. a library?

Thank you for your help!

Here is an example:

```
library(stargazer)
library(margins)

x <- lm(mpg ~ cyl * hp + wt, data = mtcars)
stargazer(x, out = 'foo.html', type = 'html') # This produces the desired outcome for the linear model

m <- margins(x)
summary(m) # I like to create a similar table as above for these results
```

Comment: Why are you making an _HTML_ table for an academic _paper_ ?

Comment: @jay.sf I know it sounds crazy, and it is, but if we have co-authors who insist on using say Word, sometimes it's easier to import an HTML table into the Word document.

Comment: @jay.sf it's as Jeremy K. says. Not all my co-authers are familiar with using latex. So we use Word. And yes I regret it. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rather hackish idea using `texreg`. Use the base model `x` and, using the `override .*` options of the `texreg::*reg` functions, put in the AMEs. When you first create tables for the base models without overiding anything, the AME tables will look similar.

The AMEs should be extended by a preceding `NA` for the intercept and a following for the interaction (just to get the AMEs congruent to the coefficients). To ged rid of the GOFs use `readLines` identify the corresponding lines and omit them. `cat` saves the code into a file in your working directory.

```
sm <- rbind(NA, summary(m), NA)

library(texreg)

ame <- list(l=x, custom.model.names="AME", override.coef=sm[, 2], digits=3,
            override.se=sm[, 3], override.pvalues=sm[, 5], omit.coef="\\(|:", 
            caption="Average marginal effects")

## html version
ame.html <- do.call("htmlreg", ame)
tmp <- tempfile()
cat(ame.html, sep="\n", file=tmp)
ame.html <- readLines(tmp)
ame.html <- ame.html[-(el(grep("R<sup>2", ame.html)):grep("<tfoot>", ame.html))]
cat(ame.html, sep="\n", file="ame.html")


## latex version
ame.latex <- do.call("texreg", ame)
tmp <- tempfile()
cat(ame.latex, sep="\n", file=tmp)
ame.latex <- readLines(tmp)
ame.latex <- ame.latex[-(el(grep("R\\$\\^2\\$", ame.latex)):grep("multicolumn", ame.latex))]
cat(ame.latex, sep="\n", file="ame.tex")


## console version
ame.screen <- do.call("screenreg", ame)
tmp <- tempfile()
cat(ame.screen, sep="\n", file=tmp)
ame.screen <- readLines(tmp)
ame.screen <- ame.screen[-(grep("---", ame.screen)[2]:(grep("\\=", ame.screen)[2] - 1))]
cat(ame.screen, sep="\n")
```

*Note:* I tried to make the `grep`s general, but you may need to adjust them according to your model.

## Result

*(showing console)*

```
=====================
           AME       
---------------------
cyl         0.038    
           (0.600)   
hp         -0.046 ** 
           (0.015)   
wt         -3.120 ***
           (0.661)   
=====================
*** p < 0.001; ** p < 0.01; * p < 0.05
```

Comment: I like your solution very much. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `stargazer` can output your results, if you first save them, then pass them to stargazer.

By default, if we pass a normal dataframe, stargazer will produce a summary table; which is not what we want. So we set `summary = FALSE`.

```
df<- summary(m) # I like to create a similar table as above for these results
stargazer(df, type = "text", summary = FALSE)
```

You can set the above to `out = 'foo.html', type = 'html'` for your output. The above returns:

```
==================================================
  factor  AME    SE     z       p    lower  upper 
--------------------------------------------------
1  cyl   0.038  0.600 0.064   0.949  -1.138 1.214 
2   hp   -0.046 0.015 -3.191  0.001  -0.075 -0.018
3   wt   -3.120 0.661 -4.718 0.00000 -4.416 -1.824
--------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: yes i knew about that, but that does not give me a table similar to the one you get when running `stargazer(x)`.

Comment: Sorry about that.